# Android Studio: cannot resolve symbol R.id.textView

Tags: java, android

I'm currently following the Android Studio "Build Your First App" tutorial (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity) and I can't seem to get the DisplayMessageActivity working. The variable "R.id.textView" doesn't seem to exist and I can't see any differences between the tutorial and my own code. I know this is just me being stupid somewhere but I can't pinpoint it.

Here's my code for DisplayMessageActivity.java:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView); <-- Cannot resolve symbol 'textView'
        textView.setText(message);
    }
}
```

And MainActivity.java, which is trying to run it:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

When I try to run the app on the virtual device it doesn't crash, but the button which calls the DisplayMessage activity does nothing.

EDIT: As requested, the xml code for both activities:

activity_display_message.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please include the activity xml files for both activities.

Comment: check the ID you have given to the textview. it should be textView only.

Answer (score 0):

I read the tutorial and I think they missed this part of code:

```
android:onClick="sendMessage"
```

so, the code should be like this:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText" />
```

and I think that's it, let me know if it helps

Comment: Is this for "activity_main.xml"? If so, I already have this in the code. I think it's more to do with imports or setup.

Answer (score 0):

After looking more closely at @Vishal Naikawadi's comment, I realised what the problem was. `R.id.textView` is not some sort of variable, placeholder, or constant as I had assumed, it is literally getting the object with id `"textView"` (or so I think). I had accidentally changed the id of the object I was trying to reference in the visual editor, so there was no object with that id. I changed the id of the object back to the same as is referenced in the code and everything seems to be fine now.

Apologies to anyone whose time I've wasted with this, I'm really new to this concept in Java.